# x-editable custom buttons IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable, bootstrap-table

is there a way to pass an ID of a clicked button to the save handler?

for example, I define some custom buttons:

```
.fn.editableform.buttons = 
            '<button type="submit" id="btnIN" type="button" class="editable-IN btn btn-success btn-sm">IN</button>'+
            '<button type="submit" id="btnOUT" type="button" class="editable-IN btn btn-success btn-sm">IN</button>'+
'<button type="submit" id="btnAFD" type="button" class="editable-IN btn btn-success btn-sm">IN</button>'+
'<button type="submit" id="btnFFD" type="button" class="editable-IN btn btn-success btn-sm">IN</button>';
```

and then later on:
this where I catch submit buttons and where I would to get IDs of my custom buttons and proceed with my custom code...

```
that.$body.find('a[data-name="' + column.field + '"]').editable(column.editable)
                .off('save').on('save', function (e, params) {
                    console.log('test save');
                });
```

Thank for help!